# TypeScript switch-case exhaustivity checking not working?

Tags: typescript, union-types

```
const changeToInvalidations = (change: Change): Array<Invalidation> => {
  switch (change.resourceType) {
    case "brand":
      switch (change.type) {
        case "added":
          return [{ type: "page", value: "productListing" }]
        case "updated":
          return [{ type: "brand", value: change.resourceId }]
        case "removed":
          return [{ type: "brand", value: change.resourceId }]
      }
    case "product":
      switch (change.type) {
        case "added":
          return [{ type: "page", value: "productListing" }]
        case "updated":
          return [{ type: "product", value: change.resourceId }]
        case "removed":
          return [
            { type: "page", value: "productListing" }, // pagination reflow
            { type: "brand", value: change.resourceId },
          ]
      }
  }
}
```

Definition of `Change` type:

```
type Change = {
  type: "added" | "updated" | "removed"
  resourceId: number
  resourceType: "brand" | "product"
}
```

Error:

> Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'

But from reading this https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

It seems I should be good to go. What a I doing wrong?

Comment: How is `Change` defined?

Comment: @Saravana I updated the description with its definition. Hope it helps!

Comment: Possibly related to [this discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8618).

Answer (score 1):

The error message is probably referring to the missing `default:` case where no return statement is defined. If the `resourceType` or `type` property is `undefined` it will switch to the `default` case.

Comment: `resourceType` and `type` properties are null-free so I don't think that's the case. See my updated description with the definition of `Change` type.